# Intel DH61AG CPU, fans, and voltages not reading in BIOS

Tags: bios, fan, temperature, voltage

I'm looking for the cause and/or fix of an issue when during start up of the DH61AG board the fans go full speed as they normally do but stay at full speed rather than slowing. In the BIOS the PC status the fan speeds are negative, and temperatures and voltages are zero.

Here's a poorly taken photo:

[image]

The chance of this happening is rare, but I have reproduced it 9 times. It seems to be a BIOS issue since it has been reported on multiple boards, with different CPUs, RAM, HDDs and fans. I have seen it happen with a blank HDD, on Win 7, from a cold start, after stressing the system, and after normal use. I don't have the slightest clue as to what the cause might be, like I said earlier it happens randomly, not often and a tell-tale sign in that the fans stay at max speed. I let it load into windows once instead of going to the BIOS and ran HWMonitor, which picked up voltages, temps, and fan speeds.

**Edit:**

Intel got back to us saying it was a motherboard defect that was in a batch of motherboards, replacement boards were given to us.

**Edit #2:**

Later Intel gave us a BIOS update. After updating the BIOS and thorough testing, the issue did not reoccur. Check for BIOS update and if it isn't there, contact Intel for update.

Comment: What version of the BIOS are you using for that board?  The latest is currently [0031 (from 08/2011)](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=20337&ProdId=3324&lang=eng). How many different boards have you personally tried?  Have you tried a new power supply?

Comment: The BIOS is update to date, I even tried rolling back to the previous driver, but it wouldn't let me go back to the BIOS version 0023. A customer reported the problem, and with a completely different board we were able to reproduce the problem. That being said we just got the customer's board yesterday. So we have only tested two boards, but how many more boards do I really need to test to say it is independent of which DH61AG board I use? We have tried three different power supplies.

Comment: Two boards is enough, I only asked because "reported" often means "I saw it on a few message boards". ;)  If you've personally tried multiple boards with multiple PSUs, CPUs and RAM, then it's a board defect for sure, luckily(?) it does seem like it's a BIOS problem more than a real hardware problem. This wouldn't be the first (or even second) Intel Media Series board that I've seen have troubles before the 3rd BIOS release. :(

Comment: Ah sorry for the confusion, next time I will be more specific in my wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short of contacting Intel and getting them to answer that question... we can only guess.  More than likely, there is some sort of bug in the power-management system on that board.  (might be fixable with BIOS update.)

Comment: One of the boards was sent to Intel, hopefully they have more insight into the problem that I do. I had hoped that someone might suggest something that I didn't already try, or something that I may have been ignorant of.